# MongoDB: return a single field from the matched item of a sub-document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider I have the following document structure:

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectID(),
  "foo": "FOO",
  "bar": "BAR",
  "items": [
    {
      "foo": "FOO",
      "bar": "BAR",
      "name": "hello",
      "value": "50"
    },
    {
      "foo": "FOO",
      "bar": "BAR",
      "name": "bye",
      "value": "300"
    },
    {
      "foo": "FOO",
      "bar": "BAR",
      "name": "welcome",
      "value": "500"
    }
  ],
}
```

I would like to find all items that match both the following conditions:

- `name = "hello"`
- `value != 0`

And for each matched item I would like to return only the `value` field. I don't need all the other fields (`foo`/`bar` in this example).

So the ideal result should look like this:

```json
[
  { value: "50" },
  { value: "100" },
  { value: "30" },
  …
]
```

How do I do this with MongoDB?

I've tried this query:

```js
// filter
{
  items: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "hello",
      value: { $ne: "0" },
    },
  }
}

// projection
{ 
  "_id": 0,
  "items.$": 1
}
```

It matches the items correctly, but it returns the whole items and I want only a single field from it.

Sadly, I can't use projection like this: `"items.$.value": 1`.

I've also tried the following aggregation:

```js
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$items"
  }
}
{
  $match: {
    "items.name": "hello",
    "items.value": { $ne: "0" },
  }
}
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$items"
  }
}
{
  $project: {
    "value": 1
  }
}
```

It works perfectly and returns the expected result, but I have a feeling that it will have poorer performance.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with optimal performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$match: {
  items: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "name": "hello",
      "value": {
        $ne: "0"
      }
    }
  }
}
},
{
 $project: {
  items: {
    "$map": {
      input: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$items",
          "as": "i",
          "cond": {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$$i.value",
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$i.name",
                  "hello"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      as: "m",
      "in": {
        "value": "$$m.value"
      }
    }
  }
 }
 },
 {
 $unwind: "$items"
 },
  {
 "$replaceRoot": {
   "newRoot": "$items"
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Match only documents having at least 1x items.element with name:"hello" and value!=0 ( good to have index on items.name+items.value , this match stage is expected to reduce the data that you want to pass to the next stages -> less data = better performance   )
2. Filter only the values for matched items in the project stage.
   ( This will remove unnecessary items array sub-items , again less data = better performance )
3. Unwind only the already filtered ( keeping unwind in the later stages will save alot of resources if the collection is big ... )
4. replace the root with the necessary values only ( this is to have the output as in expected format  )

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WwNJXVmCAPO)

Indeed as identified simple match stage will not provide correct results and $elemMatch must be used in the first $match stage ...

Comment: Thanks! The projection stage looks pretty complicated, but the overall idea seems solid.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't we use the `$elemMatch` at the `$match` stage?

Comment: Indeed map/filter seems to add some complexity , but if too complicated you may replace them with simple project after the unwind stage ...

Comment: ah yeah $elemMatch may help reducing the initialy filtered  data even more ...

Comment: Strangely both [$match](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_q_TPMjw_ao) and [$elemMatch](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ygudvqxK9SN) seems to produce the same result.

Comment: in some cases match will produce more data then elemMatch , but the project stage above will map/filter the correct output later :)

Comment: By the way I don't think that we can use a simple project here, because in your solution it is used to filter-out individual items that doesn't match the criteria. I guess we need to use another `$match` after the unwinding in order to use a simple project in the end.

Comment: Can you please give me an example where `$elemMatch` will be a better choice? I can't quite figure out the sample data for this case. I'm getting the same results for both query options.

Comment: hmm just figured out that you need to use $elemMatch only for your case

Comment: updated my answer with the correct $match stage ...

Comment: Thanks. Do you think [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JN7Rwet5DPK) is an optimal solution? Or is it still better to use complex projection?

Comment: @SlavaFominII : It looks good and simple ,  if you have index on items->name,value seems to be OK

Comment: still my solution will be faster in cases where  you have multiple matching results with multiple elements in the items array ...  , but in general case I guess you expect fewer matchiing and fewer sub-items so your solution  is perfectly  fine ...